# Parse JSON string using C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, parsing

I am trying to parse JSON string in C# solution, but I can't get the internal/nested  arrays which start with : `",[["bd felek",0],["bdm",0],["bd",0],["bdz",`

```
["bd",[["bd felek",0],["bdm",0],["bd",0],["bdz",0,[131]],["bd fleke",0],["bd felek dfdf",0],["bdz dance practice",0,[3]],["bdz twice live",0,[131]],["bdo",0,[131]],["bd mawlaya",0]],{"a":"Uwt304b6at0ZtuU8mv8D5AyWS8wg6AQJQbYlPPS8knOVvcG","e":"1","j":"6l","k":1,"q":"ZQXxB0vG-GaPEF2RNib3gbVRXt0"}]
```

```
    var jsonser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            var obj = jsonser.Deserialize<dynamic>(SourceCodeTxt.Text);

            foreach (var x in obj)

            {

                // MessageBox.Show(x);
                String strvalue = x["value"];

            }
        }
```

Comment: You should be using JSON.NET, not `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Comment: Like @RonBeyer said, use Json.NET.  [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) for `JavaScriptSerializer` even tell you to use Json.NET

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be looking at the second index (1) of the deserialized object:

```
foreach (var x in obj[1])
{
    var value1 = x[0]; // bd felek
    var value2 = x[1]; // 0                               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use JSON.NET to better handle JSON. then you can simply do the following:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

... 

JToken obj = JToken.Parse(/* Your JSON string goes in here */);
foreach (var x in obj[1])
{
    var value1 = x[0]; // bd felek
    var value2 = x[1]; // 0                               
    ...
}
```